# Does anaerobic exercise impair wound healing?

Tags: exercise, wound-care, self-healing-repairing

Anaerobic exercise causes muscle breakdown, forcing the body to engage in protein synthesis. Wound repair consists mostly of protein synthesis. It would seem that these two processes would compete with each other for resources, resulting in slower muscle repair, slower wound healing or less complete wound healing (scarring), or some combination of the above.

Does evidence support this idea? Does heavy anaerobic exercise impair wound healing?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Your reasoning makes sense, and I would imagine that sports medicine researchers might ask such a question.

Comment: There seems to be a [decent body of research](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_exercise_alter_wound_healing) around _aerobic_ exercise, which is viewed as quite beneficial to wound healing, but I'd love to know if there's been research into the effect _anaerobic_ exercise has